# bitcoin core makefile addtions

Tags: development, compiling

I have a custom set of functions that I want to run on my bitcoin client. I have a file that I need to link to net_processing.cpp. The makefile is complicated and I do not want to break anything. How do I link my .h and .cpp files?

The files are named monitor.h/.cpp

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add them to Makefile.am. Search where net_processing.{cpp,h} are mentioned and add your own.